# filling attribute with concatenated string

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, user-management

I am looking for a way to concatenate a string and put it in one active directory user account object, to be precise, in altsecurityidentities.
The value to be input will be as following:
" which is constant, and (firstName)(whitespace)(lastname) (custom value which can be taken from another attribute, which is in form x.yyyyyyyy.z (what matters to me is yyyyyyy part (.substring(2,8)) works like charm here.
I'd like to do it for several accounts that are listed in variable of type  TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser.
So that it can be set for all accounts under $accounts variable.
So far I have the code to create the attribute value for one account listed in there:
$accounts | %{'constant value'+$*.givenname+' '+$*.surname+' '+'('+$(($_.attributename).substring(2,8))+')'}
This, i'd like to put in altsecurityidentities attribute value, log to event viewer success and errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there really just need to apply the value to the desired field:

```
$accounts | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Add @{altsecurityidentities = "constant value $($_.givenname) $($_.surname) ($($_.attributename.substring(2,8)))"} }
```

I have tidied up your code by embedding the variables in a string rather than using concatenation, which is much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, that is much cleaner, thanks.
I actually just got it right by using -identity $_.samaccountname, however, in constant value special marks are present, therefore single quote was required.